# How to unload a record in Ember 2.3.0?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am upgrading an Ember 1.13.0 application to Ember 2.3.0 and I'm facing a little issue where I am unable to unload a record from the Data Store without causing Ember to make a HTTP request. I do not want to delete the record in the server. I simply want to remove it from Ember Data Store.

I was using the following Ember DS.Store API: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_unloadRecord in Ember 1.13.0 and it worked fine. Sample:

```
this.store.find('post', 1).then(function(post) {
  this.store.unloadRecord(post);
});
```

After upgrading to 2.3.0, when I monitor the network tab in Chrome, Ember is making a GET request to `find` the record and then unload it. Because it fails to `find` (our server does not have an API to match this call), it doesn't unload the record and the changes don't appear in the UI.

I tried to fix this by instead doing something like:

```
this.store.peekRecord('posts', 1).then(function(post) {
    this.store.unloadRecord(post);
});
```

but this doesn't seem to work. What is the right way to unload a record from Ember Data without making HTTP calls? Thanks.

Comment: `peekRecord` does not return promise. Just post or null.

Comment: @Keo Then how do I unload this record?

Comment: Try `this.get('store').unloadRecord(this.get('store').peekRecord('posts', 1));`

Comment: Why do you answer in comments? :P

Comment: I am not sure if that helps, never used `unloadRecord` before. If it works I will create answer and explain why `find()` made request.

Answer (score 2):

Ember data automatically reloads records to keep them in sync with server. So `findRecord()` resolves immediately, but in background it makes request to the server and update values when it returns. This behavior was changed in `ember-data 1.13.0` and is described in [toc_new-adapter-hooks-for-better-caching](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_new-adapter-hooks-for-better-caching).

The issue with [peekRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_peekRecord) is that `peek*` methods just asks `store` and thus don't need to return promise. Therefore your code should look like this:

```
const store = this.get('store');
const post = store.peekRecord('posts', 1);
if (post) {
    store.unloadRecord(post);
}
```